# Can I buy this patent? it looks like it has expired due to not paying the fees?

Tags: patentability

In reference to the patent: [US4364234](https://www.google.com/patents/US4364234)

Do I require to get license of patent even after expiry of patent?

Comment: I think the edit may have changed the intention of the question - could OP clarify?

Answer (score 1):

The patent in question has expired. No fees or licenses are due for what it covered. However, it is possible that your product infringes on other, newer, in-force patents.